# How to open Ionic Menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to open the ionic menu, in one of my pages, but cannot open it.

I can see the hamburger button, but it does not work. Goes to the function, but does not do anything.

What am I missing here?

**Controller.js**:

```
myPeersPageController.openMenu = function(){
    console.log("In open Menu()"); // it comes here
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(); //have injected $ionicSideMenuDelegate
}
```

**page.html**:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive" >
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="myPeersPageController.openMenu()"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons> 
  </ion-nav-bar>
```

**router.js**:

```
.state('mypeers',{
        url : '/mypeers',
        templateUrl : 'peers/my_peers/my_peers.template.html'
    })
```

What syntax am I missing?

Comment: Anyway, i feel like you could just get the ionic side-menu starter from github, see how it works and do the same https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a menu defined...

You're missing

`<ion-side-menu-content>` element..

EG :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      Content!
      <button ng-click="toggleLeftSideMenu()">
        Toggle Left Side Menu
      </button>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      Left Menu!
    <ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
</body>
```

Reference : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/